# Polynomials that are divisible by two numbers only.

Tags: functions, ring-theory

Suppose $f(x)=ax+b$ is our polynomial over $\mathbb{R[x]}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ either $2|f(x)$ or $3|f(x)$. Show that either for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, $2|f(x)$ or for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3|f(x)$.

I have tried to assume $f(0)=b$ is divisible by $3$ and hope to show for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $3|f(x)$. However, I am really stuck and not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: polynomial remainder theorem. okay for integer coefficient cases.

Comment: Are $a,b$ assumed to be integers?  If not, what does it mean for an integer to divide a real?  Maybe you didn't mean $\Bbb R$ = reals?

Comment: @BillDubuque As in $f$ is a polynomial that take integers to integers, I don't know however if that implies $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z[x]}$

Comment: In general, there are rational polynomials which take integers to integers.  In this case, however, the assumption gives that $f(0)=b$ is an integer and $f(1)-f(0)=a$ is also an integer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr On a unrelated node, will this still be the case if the degree of $f(x)$ is higher though? Obviously $f(1)-f(0)$ won't be as useful.

Comment: No, for example, $\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x$ will always turn integers into integers, but the coefficients are not integers.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sorry I meant $f(x)$ that possesses the property I gave in the question. $f(x)$ maps every integer to integer that is either divisible by 2 or 3.

Comment: No, $\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2+\frac{2x}{3}$ is always divisible by $2$, for any integer input.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at $x=0$ to get $f(0) = b$ is a great idea.
Suppose $2\mid f(0) = b$ than $3\not\mid f(0) = b$, with other words $b = 2n$ where $3\not\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Thus $f(x) = ax + 2n$ is not divisible by $3$ because $2n$ is not (we cannot factor out a $3$).
This means for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $2\mid f(x)$.

The same argument holds if $3\mid b$ and $2\not\mid b$.

Comment: Why can't $3$ divide $f(0)$?

Comment: Because you state for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ **either** $2\mid f(x)$ **or** $3\mid f(x)$, that is not both right?